# timerset.addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname

```
timerset.addEventListener is not a function
```

I am getting the above error when I run the following code. Why is that?

```js
var timerset = document.getElementsByClassName("newgameTButton");

function Display() {
  setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
  var count = 0;

  function myTimer() {
    if (count !== 9) count++;
    else {
      count = 0;
      textInfo = 'Timeout';
      // this.context.newGame();
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
  }
}

// for (var i = 0; i < timerset.length; i++){
timerset.addEventListener("click", Display);
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [document.getElementsByClassName() :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> The `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an
> array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
> class name(s).

#### [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> The EventTarget method `addEventListener()` sets up a function that
> will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the
> target. Common targets are **Element**, **Document**, and **Window**

---

As you can read from the above references taken from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) that `getElementsByClassName()`  returns an array-like object and `addEventListener()` can be applied on elements,documents and window but not on any kind of arrays directly.

You have to add event listeners to an element and not array of elements. `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements ( or more specifically, **NodeList object** which is like an **array of elements**) at once and hence you can't directly apply `addEventListener` on it.

You can solve the problem by iterating over the `timerset` variable and call addEventListener on each item/element using a loop.

---

So, after applying the above-mentioned changes, the following code works -

```js
var timerset = document.getElementsByClassName("newgameTButton");

function Display() {
  setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
  var count = 0;

  function myTimer() {
    if (count !== 9) count++;
    else {
      count = 0;
      textInfo = 'Timeout';
      // this.context.newGame();
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < timerset.length; i++) {
  timerset[i].addEventListener("click", Display);
}
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center
}

#timer {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: green;
}

.newgameTButton{
  padding: 20px;
  background-color : #0275d8;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class='newgameTButton'>Start The Timer</button>

<div id='timer'>0</div>
```

Added some CSS just for fun(I know it's bad).

Hope this helps!